# Turn off auto-collapsing for VB.NET in Visual Studio?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

The auto-collapse feature for *code* properties is neat AFTER you've got your properties all worked out, but while you're still editing them I find the feature to be REALLY annoying.

**How can you disable it?**

(I'm in VS2008 if it makes a difference)

Edit: I'm not talking about the Property Window... I'm talking about properties in code.

```
Private _firstName As String
Public Property FirstName() As String Implements IPerson.FirstName
    Get
        Return _firstName
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        _firstName = value
    End Set
End Property
```

displays as

```
Public Property FirstName()...
```

Answer (score 3):

From the EDIT menu, choose OUTLINING, STOP OUTLINING. You can also use the keyboard shortcut CTRL+M, CTRL+P.

Comment: The Properties still auto collapse, although there is no outlining to manually collapse Subs and Functions.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a "feature" of DevX Refactor for VB, which I also find *terribly* annoying. I found [this thread](http://community.devexpress.com/forums/t/75568.aspx) on their forum which provides a couple of suggested solutions:

- Add a key to the registry to make the DevExpress menu visible in VS and then go to the options page to disable auto-collapse or
- Install a newer version of the add-in (Release 9.1.4 or above) which apparently doesn't behave this way anymore.

Answer (score 0):

The stop outlining option never works for me.  Also the Ctrl+M, Ctrl+M option only seems to work if I have the region collapsed highlighted.  Ctrl+M, Ctrl+P does nothing for me.  I went into options and unchecked the enter Outlining mode, but that didn't do anything either.  At one point, when I had VS 2005 (now I have 2008), I managed to turn it off through a regedit hack.  Though once I had to re-install VS 2005 and forgot the hack, so I've been living with this ever since.  It's ultra annoying when you are looking for something where you are looking for a pattern of code and not the specific words of the code.  I don't know why it is, but I do that a lot.  Any helpwould be appreciated.  Ty.

Answer (score -1):

When the window is open, click on the pin in the upper right hand corner (the middle icon between the X and the down arrow).  When you're done, click it again to enable auto hide again.

Comment: It appears that Larsenal is referring to the Outlining feature, not the auto-hiding feature of the floating windows.